# Distribution of the sum reciprocal of primes $\le 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, fractions

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{43}+\cdots \le 1 $$

This is an interesting infinite summation. This is very closely resembling my other problem with has to do with the distribution of composites. That other problem is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351423/does-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-composites-that-are-le-1). The same rules of that other summation apply, but it's good to repeat them :).

Rules of this summation:

1) All terms of the summation must be reciprocal of some prime. For example, $\frac{1}{6}$ could never be a term because 6 is not a prime number.

2) The next term must be the largest reciprocal term that does not allow the entire sum to be $>1$. The next term also must be < the term before it.

3) The sum must also be permanently less than $1$ if you were to stop at a number $\lt \infty$. If you were to stop on term $\infty$, then the sum would amount to exactly $1$ by definition.

Now that you know the rules, we must rewrite the summation in a different way in order to propose my question in a reasonable manner. $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\cdots\le 1$$ As a mote of clarification, $a, b, c, d$, etc. represent $2, 3, 7, 43$, etc. respectively.

The question:

-Envision $ f(1)=a, f(2)=b, f(3)=c$, and so on. Keep in mind there are an infinite number of terms, thus an infinite number of variables to represent primes. My question is what function, $f(n)$, could hold this property and maintain true no matter what term you are at.

-One who is loving this must remember that $a, b, c, d$, etc. are integers rather than fractions in this case and therefor $f(1) \not= 1/a, f(1) \not= 1/b$, etc.
The reciprocal however is the form in which the numbers have that interesting property.

-What is $f(n)$? (The primary question)

-When answering this question, do the following, please provide some form of evidence or explain your case. If I missed something obvious, please let me know what that is with a website in the comments.

Have a great day! Thanks!

Comment: I cannot answer this question, but if you are interested, the next few primes are 1811, 654149, 27082315109, 153694141992520880899, and 337110658273917297268061074384231117039. I can keep going, but they are getting very large.

Comment: OEIS has the sequence listed as ["Slowest-growing sequence of primes whose reciprocals sum to 1"](https://oeis.org/A075442).

Comment: @MarcusM What a curious title OEIS has for the sequence!  Since the number of digits roughly doubles every term, I think there are much slower-growing sequence with this reciprocal sum (even https://oeis.org/A225669 sort of qualifies since it takes more terms to reach 10-20 digits).  It's certainly the lexicographically first sequence, though.

Comment: That's pretty cool, I never even knew it was on OEIS.

Comment: @AAron: It's always best to check. ;-$)$

Answer (score 1):

This function can be defined recursively as
$$f(a) = NP\Big{(}\big{(}1-\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}\frac{1}{f(k)}\big{)}^{-1}\Big{)}$$
where $NP(x)$ is the [next prime function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NextPrime.html). In other words, you look for the closest prime higher than the minimal number you need to keep the sum less than one in order to find $f(a)$. This sum can therefore not be expressed explicitly due to the "next prime" function used in the recursion.